# How to create a request with WS-A attributes in Spring-integration xml

Tags: spring, spring-integration, mq

Please can you help in creating a request that includes WS-A parameters
From:
To:
etc

```
<int:chain input-channel="msoapInChannel" output-channel="justLog">
<ws:header-enricher >
    <ws:soap-action value="http://yeah.com/Txns/port/sPortType/getesRequest"/>
</ws:header-enricher>
<ws:outbound-gateway uri="http://g.tst.b.l/wsb/router"/>
</int:chain>
```

I want to add wsa:From wsa:To to the request

> Error: 1100 A header representing a Message Addressing Property is not
>   present. (Reason: the required header element wsa:From is absent)

How to do this in xml based config?

EDIT:
We create request and use JMS queues. The request looks like below

```
String requestXml =  
"<getnNames xmlns=\"http://b.do.com/DTositeTxns/port\">" +
    "<RequestControl xmlns=\"http://www.im.com/mm/schema\">" + 
"<requestID>123896</requestID>" +
"<DLControl>" + 
    "<requesterName>LW</requesterName>" + 
    "<requesterLocale>RTnl</requesterLocale>" + 
"</DLControl>" +
    "</RequestControl>" +
    "<InquiryParam xmlns=\"http://www.im.com/mm/schema\">" + 
"<tcrmParam name=\"identiftionNumber\">" + bn + "</tcrmParam>" + 
"<tcrmParam name=\"PartficationType\">1000001</tcrmParam>" +
"<tcrmParam name=\"Filter\">ACTIVE</tcrmParam>" + 
    "</InquiryParam>" +
"</getnNames>" ;

TextMessage outMessage = session.createTextMessage(requestXml);
```

and send to queue.
If I use soapenv:Body, the request is not accepted as valid. So my request is only tags inside body. Not sure how to add header bits.

Please point me to an example that creates request with wsa:To and wsa:From , Relates To , Fault to etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wsa:From` and `wsa:To` are `Element` headers, they are not simple strings like the mentioned `soap-action`. There the `<ws:header-enricher>` won't help you.

However you still can declare a bean for the plain `<int:header-enricher>` and provide a `javax.xml.transform.Source` for your headers as values.

Starting with *version 5.0*, the Spring Integration's `DefaultSoapHeaderMapper` can add elements into the `<soapenv:Header>`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/ws.html#ws-message-headers.

See the sample there is Docs:

```
Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();

String authXml =
     "<auth xmlns='http://test.auth.org'>"
           + "<username>user</username>"
           + "<password>pass</password>"
           + "</auth>";
headers.put("auth", new StringSource(authXml));
...
DefaultSoapHeaderMapper mapper = new DefaultSoapHeaderMapper();
mapper.setRequestHeaderNames("auth");
```

**UPDATE**

The `<ws:outbound-gateway>` has an attribute like:

```
<xsd:attribute name="request-callback" type="xsd:string">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
Reference to a Spring Web Services WebServiceMessageCallback. This enables changing
the Web Service request message after the payload has been written to it but prior
to invocation of the actual Web Service.
                </xsd:documentation>
                <xsd:appinfo>
                    <tool:annotation kind="ref">
                        <tool:expected-type type="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceMessageCallback"/>
                    </tool:annotation>
                </xsd:appinfo>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>
```

So, what you need is to configure a bean for the `ActionCallback` and refer to it from this attribute.

More info about `ActionCallback` is in the Spring WS [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/#_code_webservicemessagecallback_code).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. We are not using Spring 5.0. I don't know how to use the bean in my - int:chain, please can you point me to an example wsa attributes. I want to create a header like the below - <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"> <wsa:Action>http://to.com/teTxns/port/nsPortType/getRequest </wsa:Action><wsa:From><wsa:Address>http://servicespecifications.st.l/ivcent/cm/lb</wsa:Address></wsa:From><wsa:MessageID>uuid:9bc5153c-a1e2-4a4f-832e-005b55f7d936</wsa:MessageID> <wsa:To>http://b.com/iteTxns/port/nsPortType</wsa:To> </soapenv:Header>

Comment: If you don't use Spring Integration `5.0.x`, then it's not going to work: it's just not supported in the previous version yet... I'll think a bit letter how to help you with the previous version.

Comment: You may consider to use `WebServiceTemplate` directly though. This way you have all the control over message and its headers to send.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about WebServiceTemplate. will that work with JMS queue? I have added code that I was using for a different service, that does not require wsa and it works fine [not using WebServiceTemplate]

Comment: I'm talking about this project https://projects.spring.io/spring-ws/. That is exactly on what Spring Integration WS is based. What you show with JMS code is fully not related to the SOAP WebServices. Not sure why are you mixing and confusing us...

Comment: Hi Artem, I have a REST endpoint, which creates a JMS TextMessage using the requestXml [as posted in question], and sends to JMS Queue [Websphere]. I use a router and put message in that channel outbound gateway [as posted in the question]. In my logs this channel is not having the wsa:To. please let me know how can I set them ?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Hello Artem, Thanks. I am implementing WebServiceMesageCallback, but not sure how to add  SoapHeaderElement inside another SoapHeaderElement

Comment: Why that `ActionCallback` doesn't work for you? See its JavaDocs for more info.

Comment: Thanks Artem. created a bean class that extends ActionCallback and used Addressing10() for AddressingVersion. [Not sure why URL 'to' can not be set from outside through a setter]